# Should I keep a pool of DefaultHttpClient, or create a new one for each request?

Tags: android, httpclient, connection-pooling

My Android app uses DefaultHttpClient to communicate with the server.

I send maybe ten requests per minute, usually two or three at the same time.

Should I create a connection pool, or is it OK, resource ways, to create a new instance for each request.

Comment: You can reuse the same instance of the client - there is no need to create a separate instance for each request.